# Restarting loop and editing original list if condition False

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I'm doing some operations on a list with a `for` loop and I need to remove elements of that list when an `if` condition is not met and then do the operations again.

I've seen the [calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886171/how-to-restart-a-program-at-a-certain-point-in-python) (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084020/python-looping-and-program-restart-if-true)) example where they use a `while` loop but I haven't been able to adapt that to my problem.

Here is an example of what I want to do

```py
a = [[9,8,7], [6,5,3,4]] # different length sublists, elements are not repeated
results = [[] for i in range(len(a))]

for i in range(len(a)):   
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        results[i].append(a[i][j]/4)
# see below for explanation for this step
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        if results[i][j] <1:
            del a[i][j]
            print('element',j,'removed from sublist',i)
            break
        else:
            continue
# when there is an element that doesn't met the condition I want to remove 
# that element and restart the calculation for that step, in this case i=1 
# but this depends on the list

# The calculation is then done for the list with the element removed
# this is way I'm repeating the code below (which I want to avoid)

results = [[] for i in range(len(a))]
for i in range(len(a)):   
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        results[i].append(a[i][j]/4)
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        if results[i][j] <1:
            del a[i][j]
            print('element',j,'removed from sublist',i)
            break
        else:
            continue
print(results)
```

Some problems:

1. I cannot check the values of `results` for each `j` step in my real code since `results[i]` is a model class and it's done for all the elements in `results[i]` simultaneously (this is why the double for loop in the example).
2. I think the code works as it is for this simple example but it could be time consuming for larger lists and more complex calculations. For example if I change my list to `a = [[9,8,7], [6,5,3,2,4]]` I'd have to include more for loops.
3. I could use something like `range(restart, len(a))` in the second `for i` loop, but the problem of point 2 remains and it would append the new results to the old ones, e.g. `results = [[2.25, 2.0, 1.75], [1.5, 1.25, 0.75, 1.0, 1.5, 1.25, 1.0]]` instead of `results = [[2.25, 2.0, 1.75], [1.5, 1.25, 1.0]]`.

Is there a better way of doing this? Maybe with a `while` loop? I would be OK with restarting the calculation from `i=0` if there isn't another way and if I don't have to include more `for` loops for larger lists with more elements.

Comment: Why have you posted the same code twice?

Comment: @Sheldore you mean to check `a[i][j]/4<1` before apending in results? This is explained in the question, I can't directly check that in the real code since `results` is the result of fitting a model to a data set. Regarding your second comment, this is part of my problem, the first time I generated a new list where an element has been removed, then I have to do the calculation again for the new list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be very pythonic but this is what worked for me.

```
a = [[9,8,7], [6,5,3,4]]
results = [[] for i in range(len(a))]

res=0
while res<1:  
    for i in range(len(a)):   
        for j in range(len(a[i])):
            results[i].append(a[i][j]/4)
        for j in range(len(results[i])):
            res = results[i][j]
            if res < 1:
                del a[i][j]
            print('element',j,'removed from sublist',i)
            res=10
print('new a =', a)
```

However, this doesn't work if there is more than one element in a sublist meeting the criterion since indexes will not be the same. If that is the case, `break` can be used to interrupt the for loops and start again with the updated list.

```
a = [[9,3,7], [1,5,2,4]]
res=0
while res<1:  
    print(a)
    results = [[] for i in range(len(a))]
    for i in range(len(a)):   
        for j in range(len(a[i])):
            results[i].append(a[i][j]/4)
        for j in range(len(results[i])):
            print(i, j, results[i][j])
            res = results[i][j]
            if res < 1:
                del a[i][j]
                print('element',j,'removed from sublist',i)
                break
        if res < 1:
            print('restarting while loop')
            break
print('new a =', a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have repeated the code twice.

If you want to give the value of 1 to the variable i and 'restart' the loop is better if you use a while loop. For example:

```
while i <= len(a):

       # your code
       # restar i value when you need it using:
       i = 1;
```

I don't know when you want to restart the value of i, but you can try in this in your else, before continue clausule.

```
i = 1
```

Comment: I repeated the code so that the calculation is done on the new list. The value of `i` where I want to restart the calculation will depend on the sublist that contains an element that doesn't met the `if` condition. I'll try to edit my question to make it more clear.